# i am unable to set my picker relative to my jtable column

Tags: java, swing, datepicker, jtable

```
  table_model = new DefaultTableModel(header, 3) {

         };

         table = new JTable(table_model) {
             @Override
             public boolean editCellAt(int row, int column) {

                 if (column == 3) {
                     Object value=getValueAt(row, column);
                     String date=new Date().toString();
                     if(value!=null){
                         date=value.toString();
                     }

                     dateTextField=new ObservingTextField(row,column);

                     dateTextField.setText(date);
                     DatePicker dp = new DatePicker(dateTextField, Locale.US);  

                     JPanel panel=new JPanel();

                     Date selectedDate = dp.parseDate(textField.getText());
                     dp.setSelectedDate(selectedDate);
                     dp.start(textField);
                     return false;
                 } else {
                     return true;
                 }
             }

             @Override
             public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                 return editCellAt(row, column);
             }

         };
```

i want to set my datepicker according to my jtable column.that is is set column3 as birthday column.if user clicks birthday column the calender is dispalying.but the problem is is displaying top of the screen.but i want to dispaly accirding to the corresnding column below it.

Comment: What's the DatePicker?

Comment: How about instead, you create a custom cell editor instead? In fact, doesn't `DatePicker` come with on?

Comment: date picker is nothing to get date from calender

Answer (score 1):

You can use JTable's method

```
public Rectangle getCellRect(int row, int column, boolean includeSpacing)
```

to get the cell bounds and set the control coordinates.

Comment: how to set date picker to that corresponding row and column